# Hard Disk is full of Sql server logs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, log

SQL server created a lot of SQLDump.txt files in log folder I'm using SQL server 2017, but I have two databases in My SQL server. I find out my problem isn't about to shrink Ldf file I checked it out. I researched about Error Logs, SQL log, and transaction log. I don't know how to find out which of them are my issues?

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4494351) - 14.0.2014.14 (X64)
>   Apr  5 2019 09:18:51   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation 
>   Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0
>    (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have something seriously wrong going inside the SQL Server and that is why it is producing so many dumps and if you look closely dumps file `SQLDumpxxx` are getting dumped every minute of so this may be due to bug in SQL Server or sql server facing some exception because of queries running. I would start by looking whether the SQL Server is patched to latest SP and CU or not. If you run `select @@version` and add the output in the question I can tell you the SP level. You can also find SP/CU information about SQL Server 2017 on [SQLServerbuild.blogspot.com](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).

Similar question discussed on [This Thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87112/the-sql-server-log-folder-is-expanding-because-of-the-sql-dump-files-what-to-do)

MS engineers are the best person to analyze these dumps and tell you what is causing this but before opening case with MS please make sure the SQL Server instance is patched to latest SP and CU so that you rule out all the possibility of bug. If you go to them without patched SQL Server they are most likely to ask you to update to latest SP.

Some links which show how to analyze dumps

[SQL Server Diagnostics (Preview)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview/)

[Looking deeper into SQL Server using Minidumps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2009/09/11/looking-deeper-into-sql-server-using-minidumps/)

[Steps to Catch a Simple “Crash Dump” of a Crashing Process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/)

[Extracting Information from Crash and Hang Dumps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cobold/2017/03/01/ax_dmp_analysis/)

The first 2 links should be good if you want to try it yourself but my suggestion would be to make sure latest SP and CU is there and if that does not solves the issue raise case with MS.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4494351) - 14.0.2014.14 (X64)

You can see the version is RTM you need to apply [SQL Server 2017 CU15](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4498951/cumulative-update-15-for-sql-server-2017) and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: I updated, but of course, it didn't solve.

Comment: Can you add output of sp_readerrorlog in the question. And how do you say it did not solve, are you still seeing the dumps?