# Why is Microsoft SQL Server creating a ton of dump files?

Tags: sql-server, dump, polybase

How to determine what is causing Microsoft SQL Server to create dump files over and over taking up 170 GB of disk space? How do I troubleshoot what is causing the dumps?

The path of the dump files is

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSQL\Log\Polybase\dump`

Can I delete these?

I have looked at [The SQL server Log folder is expanding because of the SQL Dump files (what to do with it ?)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87112/the-sql-server-log-folder-is-expanding-because-of-the-sql-dump-files-what-to-do) but it doesn't really answer my question - it mainly states to contact Microsoft.

Comment: What are the file extensions of the files there? Did you open any of them and see what they contain?

Answer (score 2):

Since these dumps are being created specifically in the polybase subdirectory, you may want to focus specifically on polybase dumps.

At this link, Niels Berglund shows how TCP protocol being disabled for SQL Server connectivity lead to multitudinous polybase dumps being created.
https://nielsberglund.com/2019/11/20/fix-polybase-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/

Answer (score 1):

You can [check the SQL Server Error Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-ver15) to get more information as to why dump files were generated. Microsoft also provides the `sys.dm_server_memory_dumps` dmv for [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-server-memory-dumps-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but it isn't clear to me how that dmv would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Service for "Sql Server Polybase Data Movement" is Stopeed in Sql Server Configuration manager. Screenshot attached below -

Otherwise if you don't use Polybase you can Uninstall it from you standalone installation. Guide to uninstall is at msdn link below1

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx

[image: Stop Polybase Service in sql server configuration manager]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were 2 instances of sql... MSSQLSERVER and MSSQLSERVER2. Looking at services, I found a SQL Polybase (MSSQLSERVER2) which was the one that generated the files that were filling the hard drive, in a brutal way. So leave them as a stopped service and in manual type, then stop all MSSQLSERVER2 services, and leave them as manual. Delete the dmp files from the dump folder, and until today the files do not appear .dmp. It was my solution to this problem!

What I did prior to that process is to pass all databases to the MSSQLSERVER instance. and everything keeps working perfectly.

Maybe you have to do the same.

Comment: ola aqui tines escribir en ingles

Comment: The issue was similar in that a copy of sql running and was creating error files and dumping them to the hard disk. Thanks for follow up.